# Example of jax-rs with struts

Tags: java, struts2, jax-rs

Can anyone share a simple example to create json from jax-rs with struts framework. I have tried to find an example. But I didn't get any suitable documentation for this.

Comment: Please elaborate more. Struts is MVC. Why you want to use it with JAX-RS?

Comment: Have you tried Struts JSON Plugin?

Comment: In Struts 2 , you can use `“struts2-json-plugin.jar”` library for converting object into JSON. where as Jax rs is used to implement webservices which returns any data like XML,JSON,Text,HTML,etc . you can even refer : [this link](https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/)

Comment: yes i wanted to create data in more than one form in json and XML so i used rest.. now that is working with the help of jersey